# How do I make a referral program in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I am trying to create a program where other users can sign up using links of other already registered users. So, when one is referred, this is how the url would look like

```
mywebsite.com/register?ref_id=555 // ref_id is existing user id
```

I am using the default Laravel auth. There is a hidden input value which would contain the value of `ref_id` if it exists. My database has a column called `referred_by` which is an `INT`and set to `null` by default. When someone registers using the link with ref_id, that id will get saved into that user row. 
But the problem is it's getting saved as null everytime.

This is how the validator looks like in `Auth/RegisterController.php`

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:40',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:40',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'account_name' => 'required|max:80',
        'account_number'=> 'required|max:15',
        'bank_name'=> 'required|max:30',
        'phone_number' => 'required|max:15',
        'ref_id' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'username' => 'required|max:15|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

and this is how the create method look like

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'account_name'=> $data['account_name'],
        'account_number' => $data['account_number'],
        'bank_name'=> $data['bank_name'],
        'phone_number'=> $data['phone_number'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'referred_id' => (int)$data['ref_id'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Since ref_id is saved in the hidden input field as a string, I tried converting it into an integer before putting into the database but I am not able to get it to work.
I am really confused on how I can achieve this. 
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure all of those are `$fillable` on the User model?

Comment: First check if the data has ref_id by a `dd($data)` and if it does, then check if the referred_id is in `$fillable` of the user model

Comment: Yes, they are fillable. This is how the array looks like  protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'account_name', 'account_number', 'bank_name','referred_by', 'username', 'phone_number', 'password',
    ]; @upful

Comment: I am actually kinda noob in Laravel. Can you please tell me how to check if the data has ref_id ?
Thanks in advance. @Paras

Comment: I see `referred_by` not `referred_id` 

Comment: Looks like a typo in `referred_id`

Comment: The column name in the database is referred_by and hidden input value has the name of ref_id. So, there is no typo I guess. @Paras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your create function has `'referred_id' => (int)$data['ref_id'],`
but your column name is `referred_by`, so just change `referred_id` to `referred_by`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems like this was the problem. It was such a silly mistake where I spent 3hrs like an idiot. Thank you very much for pointing out the mistake and helping me. Seems like I walked in the right path.