# Referral point system

Tags: laravel

I have to implement a referral system with laravel.

In practice, when a user A registers by typing in the form also a referral id, the user B (the one to which the referral code is associated) must receive 50 points (in the balance field in MySQL must be added 50).

Do you know how to do it? I specify that the referral code must be the user's id B.

Comment: This is too general. What did you try so far?

Comment: I have to make sure that:

when a user signs up, in addition to email, username and password, he can also type in the id of a friend of his.

At that moment, his friend must receive 50 bonus points.

Comment: I'm sorry if you do not understand very well but I'm not good English.

Comment: I'm saying, it sounds like you're looking for a tutorial. This site is more aimed at specific technical questions, not step-by-step instructions. Someone who reads your question has no idea how advanced your knowledge of PHP/Laravel is. If you show some code it is easier to guide you. What you want is to set up your controller so that any POST request submitted by your form will extract the referral code, then using a foreign key relationship associate that with the primary key (user id) of user B. Then you can update User B's points field.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738233/how-do-i-make-a-referral-program-in-laravel ?